# Google Analytics & Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm tracking a video in Google Analytics using the following -

```
<a href="http://youtu.be/4WQ-v9VBupY" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'SU Class Demo']);"></a>
```

...however, based on the documentation I've read so far, the above code is only going to track the "Play" events, and I need to track **Play**, **Pause**, and **Stop**.

Is it as simple as this? (Just adding **Pause**, and **Stop** after the "Play" string?)

`...'_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Pause', 'Stop', 'SU Class Demo'`

Comment: The code you posted is not going to do what you're thinking it will. All you're doing here is linking to a youtube video. And since you're linking to an external domain, there's a very good chance that your event won't be tracked.

Comment: If you eventually migrate to UA and start using GTM, there's a tutorial here (http://www.cardinalpath.com/youtube-video-tracking-with-gtm-and-ua-a-step-by-step-guide/) on how to track Youtube videos.

Comment: @PhilipWalton - What do you recommend in this situation. Basically, I want to have the embedded video on the site, and track it's usage. There must be a way of doing it, but I'm getting lost with it.